# Oracle match columns from 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, compare, inner-join

I have 2 tables as below and i would like to include only the records from Table 1 that are present in Table 2 based on the column 'Product'

If any single row per ID is matched then, it has to be included in the output table(the match does not have to be in an order) ex: PRD-B,PRD-C can also match PRD-C,PRD-B but it has to be an entire match.

I will not be able to make any changes to my data model

### Table 1

```
 ID   |   State      |     Product     |
 ---------------------------------------
 1         FL                PRD-A
 1         GA                PRD-B
 1         CA                PRD-D,PRD-E
 2         MN                PRD-K
 3         OH                PRD-B,PRD-C
 4         PR                PRD-F,PRD-Z
 4         MT                PRD-Z,PRD-A
```

### Table 2

```
 |  Product      |
----------------
 PRD-A
 PRD-C,PRD-B
 PRD-F
 PRD-A,PRD-Z
```

Here is the required output

### Table 3

```
ID       |      State     |      Product    |
-----------------------------------------------
 1               FL              PRD-A
 1               GA              PRD-B
 1               CA              PRD-D,PRD-E   
 3               OH              PRD-B,PRD-C
 4               MT              PRD-Z,PRD-A
```

I have tried to use joins but have no luck in finding complete matches, any ideas or help is appreciated.

### EDIT

```
select distinct a.ID
  from Table_1 a
  inner join Table_2 b
    on trim(upper(b.Product)) = trim(upper(Product))
```

This is part of the query i have

Comment: Can you add the query you have tried?

Comment: Fix your data model.  You shouldn't be storing lists as delimited strings.

Comment: Given that there's no `JJAR_ACTIVITY_ID` on Table_1 I suspect your example query needs some editing. I've copied your query into the body of the question. Please edit the query in the question (there's an [edit] button immediately above the tags) and update it so it matches the example table you've included in the question. Thanks.

Comment: select distinct a.ID from Table_1 a inner join Table_2 b on trim(upper(b.Product)) = trim(upper(Product))

Comment: cannot make any changes to data model

Comment: @RData - once again, please edit the query in the question. Using comments to convey additional information is a bad idea, as it requires all those who wish to answer to search through the comments, leading to inaccurate or incorrect answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    with tbl1 as (
    select distinct a.id, a.state trim(regexp_substr(trim(upper(b.Product)),'[^,]+', 1, level) ) product
      from table_1 a
       connect by regexp_substr(trim(upper(a.Product)) , '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
       order by id),
    tbl2 as (
    select distinct trim(regexp_substr(trim(upper(b.Product)),'[^,]+', 1, level) ) product
      from table_2 b
       connect by regexp_substr(trim(upper(b.Product)), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null)
select distinct tbl1.*
  from tbl1
  inner join tbl2
    on tbl1.product = tbl2.product
```